# Show that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ if $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)\;{\rm d}x=0$ for all $g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous, with $g(a)=g(b)=0$.

Tags: calculus

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, with the property that
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)\;{\rm d}x=0
$$
for all $g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous, with $g(a)=g(b)=0$. Show that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.

**Note**: I know there are many similar questions, but not with the extra criterion that $g(a)=g(b)=0$.

Comment: The additional criterion is irrelevant. This is still a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose to the contrary that $f(x)\neq 0$ for some $x\in(a,b)$, then there exists some sub-interval $x\in(c,d)\subset(a,b)$ for which $f((a,b))\subset (\varepsilon,\infty)$ for some $\varepsilon>0$.  Let $g$ be the indicator function on $(c,d)$ [you need to slope up and down outside of $(c,d)$ but inside $(a,b)$ to make $g$ continuous], then the integral of the product is bigger than $(b-a)\varepsilon$, a contradiction.

Comment: Actually, you need to "slope up and down" *inside* of $(c,d)$ since you don't know the sign of $f$ outside $(c,d)$. Other than that +1 that's the right idea.

Comment: @dxiv You have some outside space before the sign changes.  There's a ton of things you can do though; it's a silly problem.